# Calculate sum of ascii values of email address in php

Tags: php

I want to echo the sum of the lowercase ascii values of a email address. For example:

a@b.nl

97(a) + 64(@) + 98(b) + 46(.) + 110(n) + 108(l) = 523

Any idea how to calculate this in PHP?

Comment: And what you tried by yourself?

Comment: Found a snippet but did not work... http://snipplr.com/view/9947/

Comment: try the function ord()

Comment: @Gerard your code works. But you want only lowercase characters sum?

Comment: @Gerard 1. Please add your attempts no matter if they throw an error or what 2. What do you mean with *lowercase ascii values* ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use [ord()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_ord.asp) in PHP:

```
ord()
```

example

```
$str = "a@b.nl";
$sum = 0;

$arr1 = str_split($str);
foreach($arr1 as $item){
   $sum += ord($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function asciiSum($string){
    $sum = 0;
    for($i = 0;  $i < strlen($string); $i++)
       $sum += ord($string[$i]);

    return $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line solution:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map('ord', str_split('a@b.nl')));
```